# I can be 2; I can be ∞

Tags: riddle, word

I can be 2

I can be ∞

The more I have the more I wont favor you

The less I have the less fun

I bring tense to my owner

People from any part of the world knows about me.

3100 to now I still work

> I like to play board games.
>  I have faces but no expressions.

Answer (score 6):

A bit far-fetched, but still. You are

> Elo rating in chess (or other games)

I can be 2
I can be ∞

> Well, Elo rating system is technically unbounded, so the rating of a player can have any value and even be potentially infinite (although it's highly unlikely due to the possibility of draws, so even the so-called "God player" will have finite rating)

The more I have the more I wont favor you

> Well, the greater is the opponent rating, the less are the chances to win/draw a game.

The less I have the less fun

> On the other side, it's not interesting to play and analyse at very low level. Grandmaster games are usually more interesting to watch and analyse.

I bring tense to my owner

> Of course, a high-rated player (a GM or so) will bother about playing results.

People from any part of the world knows about me.

> The rating system is global and universal, in fact, everyone who plays online chess knows about rating system (even a bit).

3100 to now I still work

> Despite official FIDE ratings are much lower than 3100 (the most top-rated GMs, including the current world champion Magnus Carlsen, have about 2900), but the top online ratings AFAIK had reached 3100ish values. Of course, Elo system still works and is a convenient way to rate chess players.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is

> the unknown from an equation.

Reasoning:

I can be 2 / I can be ∞

> That is why it is unknown

The more I have the more I won't favor you

> the more unknown the harder it is to solve

The less I have the less fun

> the exact opposite of before and this is true

I bring tense to my owner

> solving is quite stressful

People from any part of the world knows about me

> mathematics are worlwide and that is a quite good joke the "knows about me"

3100 to now I still work

> The more complex math started to appear around [3000 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics#History).